# Battlefield 3 Obscure Dogtags

Tags: battlefield-3

How do you go about unlocking some of the seemingly more obscure dogtags in BF3?
Specifically:
Dog Tag Name - Description

- 6 Wolf Moon - No one likes a lone wolf
- Bye Kitty - Scratched during the long lonely hours on watch
- Road - Highly irregular, but amusing
- Pile O Bones - Are all these even from the same person?
- Opener - Indespensable equipment for excursions
- Ace of Spades: You win some, you lose some
- Bringer of Death: Because that's what you are
- Cause of Death - Fishy abbreviation (be something to do with Call of Duty probably)
- More Dinosaurs - Because that's what we really need
- Haggard - Gets around quite a lot
- Mayan - Incredible, isn't it?
- Yarrr - Talk like a pirate

These are located towards the bottom of the dog tags page, a few rows above the Assault/Engi/Support/Recon Service Star 5+ dog tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Doctor Pepper Promotional Tags:](http://www.drpepper.com/promotions/ea/)

- 6 wolf moon
- Bye Kitty
- Opener
- Roar
- Pile O Bones

This promotion ends on 12/31, and it might already be difficult to find the specially marked Doctor Peppers for this, so if you want these, act fast :)

[Pre-Order](http://www.ea.com/news/battlefield-3-limited-edition-details-released) bonuses:

- Ace of Spades
- Bringer of Death
- Cause of Death
- More Dinosaurs
- Haggard
- Mayan
- Yarrr

For these, you have to have pre-ordered the game.  I think some of these were retailer exclusive.  It seems like at least Ace of Spades and More Dinosaurs were from Amazon.

There's a full list of all the tags and how to unlock them on [this site.](http://www.gamedynamo.com/article/showarticle/2480/en/Battlefield_3_Dog_Tags_List)